# Using Associative Array Constants in Foreach

Tags: php, foreach, constants, associative-array

I'm on **PHP7** so I have used `define()` to set an associative array as a constant like

```
define('CONSTANT_ARRAY', [
    'December 2019' => '2020-01-01',
    'July 2019' => '2019-08-01',
    "May 2019" => "2019-06-01",
    "February 2019" => "2019-03-01",
    "July 2018" => "2018-08-01",
    "November 2017" => "2017-12-01",
    "October 2017" => "2017-11-01",
    "August 2017" => "2017-09-01",
    "July 2017" => "2017-08-01",
    "June 2017" => "2017-07-01",
    "May 2017" => "2017-06-01",
    "April 2017" => "2017-05-01",
    "March 2017" => "2017-04-01",
    "February 2017" => "2017-03-01"
]);
```

I'd like to fetch this constant to use in a `foreach`loop.

```
foreach (explode(', ', CONSTANT_ARRAY) as $month => $actual_date) {
    // SOME CODE
} /* end foreach loop */

// SOME CODE TO FETCH AND DISPLAY THE RESULTS
```

Anything wrong spotted?

Comment: Why are you using `explode()`?  You just use `foreach (CONSTANT_ARRAY as ...`

Comment: @CBroe "enthusiast" means interested in as far as I know. Maybe knowing better in a particular subject makes you want to patronize people who ask for help? a bit sad :)

Comment: You do realize that that constant array has very limited value, right? You could do the same with `DateTime` class programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constant is an array, so you could just loop through it in a regulay way :

```
foreach (CONSTANT_ARRAY as $month => $actual_date) {
    // SOME CODE
} /* end foreach loop */
```

You don't need to serialize/unserialize your array since PHP 5.6+

Comment: Is there anything I should do if defining the constant array in a separate file (not part of the local php code)?